# When we go for cross apply and when we go for inner join in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012, apply

I have small question about SQL Server. When do we use `cross apply`, and when do we use `inner join`? Why use `cross apply` at all in SQL Server?

I have emp, dept tables; based on those two tables, I write an `inner join` and `cross apply` query like this:

```
----using cross apply
SELECT * 
FROM Department D 
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Employee E 
     WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID) A 

----using inner join 
SELECT * 
FROM Department D 
INNER JOIN Employee E ON D.DepartmentID = E.DepartmentID
```

Both queries return the same result.

Here why is `cross apply` needed in SQL Server? Is there performance difference? Can you please tell me?

When will we use `cross apply` and when `inner join`? Any performance difference between these queries? Please tell me which is the best way to write this query in SQL Server.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks  for given more information on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY` (same with `LEFT JOIN` and `OUTER APPLY`) are very closely related. In your example I'd assume, that the engine will find the same execution plan.

- A `JOIN` is a link between two sets over a condition
- an `APPLY` is a *row-wise* sub-call

But - as mentioned above - the optimizer is very smart and will - at least in such easy cases - understand, that it comes down to the same.

- The `JOIN` will try to **collect the sub-set and link it** over the specified condition
- The `APPLY` will try to **call the related result with the current row's values** over and over.

Differences are in calling *table-valued-functions* (should be *inline*-syntax!), with XML-method `.nodes()` and with more complex scenarios.

### One example how one could use `APPLY` to simulate *variables*

...to use the result of a *row-wise* calculation like you'd use a variable:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES('Want to split/this at the two/slashes.'),('And/this/also');

SELECT d.ID
      ,d.SomeString
      ,pos1
      ,pos2
      ,LEFT(d.SomeString,pos1-1)
      ,SUBSTRING(d.SomeString,pos1+1,pos2-pos1-1)
      ,SUBSTRING(d.SomeString,pos2+1,1000)
FROM @dummy AS d
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString) AS pos1) AS x
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString,x.pos1+1) AS pos2) AS y
```

This is the same as the following, but much easier to read (and type):

```
SELECT d.ID
      ,d.SomeString
      ,LEFT(d.SomeString,CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString)-1)
      ,SUBSTRING(d.SomeString,CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString)+1,CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString,(CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString)+1))-(CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString)+1))
      ,SUBSTRING(d.SomeString,CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString,(CHARINDEX('/',d.SomeString)+1))+1,1000)
FROM @dummy AS d
```

### One example with XML-method `.nodes()`

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(SomeXML XML)
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
(N'<root>
  <a>a1</a>
  <a>a2</a>
  <a>a3</a>
  <b>Here is b!</b>
</root>');

SELECT All_a_nodes.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @dummy
CROSS APPLY SomeXML.nodes(N'/root/a') AS A(All_a_nodes);
```

The result

```
a1
a2
a3
```

### And one example for an inlined function call

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestProduceRows(@i INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT TOP(@i) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr FROM master..spt_values
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(100),Number INT);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestData VALUES
 ('Show me once',1)
,('Show me twice',2)
,('Me five times!',5);

SELECT *
FROM TestData
CROSS APPLY dbo.TestProduceRows(Number) AS x;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestData;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestProduceRows;
```

The result

```
1   Show me once    1   1
2   Show me twice   2   1
2   Show me twice   2   2
3   Me five times!  5   1
3   Me five times!  5   2
3   Me five times!  5   3
3   Me five times!  5   4
3   Me five times!  5   5
```