# Cross apply with outer reference forces scan

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I coerce SQL into seeking against my index in this scenario?  I have a cross apply which, if fed static values seeks correctly.  If fed input from the outer rows, it fails to generate a plan.  What's the difference... should it be able to take the rows from the topmost operator and feed them into the cross apply?

```
select * 
  from AccessorGrantPermissableAssociations a
 cross apply 
     (
       select z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId, max(z.CreatedDate) CreatedDate
         -- notice forceseek (cannot generate query plan when using reference to alias 'a'
         -- works fine when provided static values
         from AccessorGrant z (forceseek)
        where 
          -- works
          z.AccessorId = 1 and z.PermissableId = 1 
          -- doesn't work
          --z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId
          and z.CreatedDate <= cast(switchoffset(@asOfMoment, '-00:00') as datetime2)
        group by z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId
     ) b
```

I can prove that the index works becuase I can execute the following with a fast seek:

```
select z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId, max(z.CreatedDate) CreatedDate
  from AccessorGrant z (forceseek)
 where z.AccessorId = 1 and z.PermissableId = 1 
   and z.CreatedDate <= cast(switchoffset(@asOfMoment, '-00:00') as datetime2)
 group by z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId
```

For your info, there is an index on AccessorGrant:
`(AccessorId, PermissableId, CreatedDate)`

Reiterate Question:
Why doesn't the same query work in a cross apply that does if its provided static values?  How can I get the most recent date for every pair of AccessibleId and PermissableId with an efficient plan?

**update plans** (pasteplan didn't work for me)
Here is a plan using `z.AccessorId = 1 and z.PermissableId = 1`:
[image]

Here is a plan using `z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId`:
[image]

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Be very careful using query hints. They are an absolute last resort and should only be used when your testing has proven they are required. In essence this is you telling the query engine that you know better than it does how to process a query. In reality this is VERY rarely the case.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41789975/5089204) I wrote some ideas about the difference of `CROSS APPLY` and `INNER JOIN`. The main difference is, that joins are done on sets, while apply is a row wise call. I'd try to change this from `cross apply` to `inner join`  with your `where` as `on`clause...

Comment: @Shnugo I appreciate the advice... but I've tried cross apply, join and CTE.  In every case, when I use a static value it works, but when I make the actual association to the outer source vars, it can't generate the plan.

Comment: @SeanLange The query hint is there to demonstrate that SQL can't generate a plan without resorting to a scan... which is the point.  If you just ran it without the hint, you might think it worked... which it doesn't because its not using a seek, and using my static demo values proves that it can.  The forceseek is necessary for the question.  Its also a good thing that I often know better than the engine how it should execute a query efficiently and can use hints effectively and sparingly toward that end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a slight variation of a classic `top-n-per-group` problem.
It can be done with `CROSS APPLY` or with `ROW_NUMBER`. The best method depends on your data distribution.

---

If we keep the `CROSS APPLY` approach, I would rewrite your query like this:

```
select * 
from 
    AccessorGrantPermissableAssociations AS a
    cross apply 
    (
        select TOP(1)
            z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId, z.CreatedDate
        from 
            AccessorGrant AS z
        where 
            z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId 
            and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId
            and z.CreatedDate <= cast(switchoffset(@asOfMoment, '-00:00') as datetime2)
        ORDER BY z.CreatedDate DESC
    ) AS b
;
```

It produces the same result, but with explicit instruction to the server to get only one row from `AccessorGrant` for each row from `AccessorGrantPermissableAssociations`. It looks like optimizer is not smart enough to convert `MAX` into `TOP(1)` when it is buried behind sub-query in this case. It can do this transformation in the simple query, but can't in this case.

If it still doesn't do seek, change the index to match the query exactly: `(AccessorId, PermissableId, CreatedDate DESC)`.

Most likely if you write the query in this form you would not need a `FORCESEEK` hint.

Comment: THANK YOU.  That was the missing piece.  I kept trying to group my data and something just broke... but ordering and taking top 1 fits perfectly with my clustered indexes and results in beautiful plans... without the hints no less.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @cocogorilla, you are welcome. I'm glad this answer was useful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Go back to `z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId` in your `b` subquery, but add `WHERE a.AccessorId = 1 and a.PermissibleId = 1` in the main query, and get rid of the `FORCESEEK` table hint.

```
select * 
  from AccessorGrantPermissableAssociations a
 cross apply 
     (
       select z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId, max(z.CreatedDate) CreatedDate
         from AccessorGrant z 
        where 
          z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId
          and z.CreatedDate <= cast(switchoffset(@asOfMoment, '-00:00') as datetime2)
        group by z.AccessorId, z.PermissableId
     ) b
    WHERE a.AccessorId = 1 and a.PermissableId = 1
```

Your CROSS APPLY is evaluated for every row in your outer query, so you want to limit the outer query as much as possible.

But really, are you not after just the max created date?  It should more properly be this:

```
select * 
      from AccessorGrantPermissableAssociations a
     cross apply 
         (
           select max(z.CreatedDate) CreatedDate
             from AccessorGrant z 
            where 
              z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId
              and z.CreatedDate <= cast(switchoffset(@asOfMoment, '-00:00') as datetime2)           
         ) b
        WHERE a.AccessorId = 1 and a.PermissableId = 1
```

Comment: 1 and 1 are placeholder values and not what I want.  I want z.AccessorId = a.AccessorId and z.PermissableId = a.PermissableId as per OP