# Does cross apply use row by row processing?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I've always thought of cross applies as a different way of doing an inner join. I've been having to re-write a bunch of code because my SR. is convinced that cross applies aren't ansi supported and also use row by row processing.

I get that an inner join is more intuitive. I also understand that I should not use a cross apply if the same thing can be accomplished with an inner join. It's just that some times I try cross applies before inner joins. I've looked at the IO statistics for cases where I can switch cross apply to inner join and they're are no differences.

My Questions then: 
1. Does cross apply use row by row processing? 
2. Should cross applies be regarded and treated like cursor's? (I.e performance hogs) 
3. Is cross apply ansi supported? 
4. What are the best real life examples of when to use and avoid cross applies?

Comment: In CROSS APPLY the function gets called over and over again, once per row... http://optimalbi.com/blog/2013/12/05/why-is-cross-apply-so-slow-part-1-function-call-overhead/

Comment: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained

Comment: You might read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41789975/5089204

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is Microsoft's syntax for standard `LATERAL JOIN`. So, the concept is in the standard, but MS implemented it before it got into the standard with its own syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does cross apply use row by row processing?

Sometimes.  So do many regular joins.  Depends on the query.  Show actual query plan in SSMS and you can see what it is doing.  Often times you will see that the `CROSS APPLY` and the equivalent traditional joins use the same query plan.  Sometimes `CROSS APPLY` will be faster.  Sometimes the JOIN will be faster.  Depends on the data, indexes, statistics, etc.

> 2. Should cross applies be regarded and treated like cursor's? (I.e performance hogs)

No.  They are not like cursors.  If not optimized by the query optimizer, they are like `LOOP JOINS`.  But they might be performance hogs.  Just like any other query.

> 3. Is cross apply ansi supported?

I don't think so, but I am not certain

> 4. What are the best real life examples of when to use and avoid cross applies?

If you have a query that returns a lot of rows in the outer part of the query, you might consider joining to a subquery rather than using a `CROSS APPLY`, anticipating that SQL Server will do a `HASH JOIN` on the two queries.  However, if SQL Server does a `LOOP JOIN` you will likely end up with the same query plan as the `CROSS APPLY`.  If you have a query with few rows in the outer and you want to look up values in another table just based on those few, then you might favor the `CROSS APPLY`, though SQL Server may choose the `LOOP JOIN` for you anyway.

As a general rule, you shouldn't use JOIN hints unless you have a darn good reason to do so.  Similarly, I wouldn't fret over using `CROSS APPLY` vs a join to a sub-query based solely on performance.  Choose the one that makes the most sense in fetching your data, and let SQL Server figure out the best way to execute it.  If it runs slowly for a particular query, then think about changing it to the other approach or providing join hints.